# How to add debugging information to Error objects when using Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

This is a common pattern in JavaScript:

```
const error = new TypeError('Unknown element type');
error.foo = foo;
throw error;
```

(i.e. attach some relevant object to an Error instance before throwing it, for debugging purposes.)

But Flow complains:

```
property `foo`
Property not found in
TypeError
```

What's the correct solution for this in Flow?

Answer (score 2):

You could make a subtype of it that's more specific:

```
class SubTypeError extends TypeError {
  foo : string;
  constructor(msg){
   super(msg);
   this.foo = '';
  }
}

const error = new SubTypeError('Unknown element type');
error.foo = 'hey';
throw error;
```

Though this won't work with class syntax transformers most likely (like babel class transformer).

Comment: Works with Babel if you use https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the error to `any` before assigning the `foo` property:

```
const error = new TypeError('Unknown element type');
(error: any).foo = 'foo';
throw error;
```